# How to get dynamically added elements name using jQuery find() method?

Tags: jquery

I practicing jQuery, I came into a scenario which requires me to get the element name that is dynamically added inside the `#field` div. my code below is working on static elements but not those elements that is manipulated dynamically.

```
//This works on static elements
$('#field').find('input, select, textarea').each( function() {       
   var name = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

I also tried:

1.

```
$('#field').get(0).find('input, select, textarea').each(function() {       
   var name = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

2. 

```
$('#field').find('input, select, textarea').each(document, function() {       
   var name = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

3. 

```
$('#field').find('input, select, textarea').get[0].each(function() {       
   var name = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

4. 

```
$(document, '#field').find('input, select, textarea').each(function() {       
      var name = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

PS: no.4 works but some elements outside the div is displayed. I want only those element inside #field div. the attempt no.1 - no.3 is not working.

Comment: I modified the question. thanks.

Comment: btw, are you sure that your #field is unique? I mean you don't have multiple `id=field` in your html file?

Comment: yes, that is a unique identifier

Comment: it seems we just find about events, I'm testing, even my answer maybe don't do it as you expect, I'm also still testing...

Comment: I updated the answer, now it's working.

Comment: converted to a snippet one

Answer (score 1):

How about onchange event?
you need to have a change event that care about changes on your input elements, also I made a button to change dynamically one of the elemtns, now whenever you change them, statically or dynamically all of them will change.

**Important note**

you need to trigger `change()` event wherever you are dynamically change your inputs, look at js section that I called `.change()` method.

```js
$('input, select, textarea').on('change', function() {
   $('#field').find('input, select, textarea').each( function()      {
     var name = $(this).attr('name');
     $(this).val(name);
   });
}); 
 
function myclick(){
  // first let's change one of them dynamically
  $("#thisone").val("hello").change();   
  return;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="field">
<input  name="saeid" value="nothing">
  <input id="thisone" name="Hdog" value="nothing">
  <input  name="jack" value="nothing">
  <input  name="maz" value="nothing">
  <input  name="banana" value="nothing">
   
</div>
<input  name="banana" value="nothing">
<input  name="banana" value="nothing">
<input  name="banana" value="nothing">
<input type="button" onclick="myclick();" value="chane one of them and update all of them">
```

Comment: I also need this approach. thanks. but i have another trigger, it is when the next button is click. what is the best approach?

Comment: in your codes, whenever you are changing the `input/select/textarea`s insdie the #field, just need to run .change() on them as well, I don't know If I got you correct

Comment: can you please explain it by code "but i have another trigger, it is when the next button is click.", I don't understand the problem.